# How to combine multi index columns with an independent colum

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to a add two independents columns to a multi index dataframe. I did for one column with:
`df = dataframe.join(pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 1), columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['New']], index = dataframe.index))`

But I' don't know if it's the right way. If is correct can I add another with the same line of code? Or there is a pythonic way

[image: in the left it's what I was tried and the righ the original dataset]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify all levels of the multiindex for any entry (i.e. for the new column too). Then you can simply write:

```
df[('New','')] = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 1), columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('A',1)]))
df[('New1','')] = range(5)
df[('New2','')] = range(10,15)
print(df)
#          A New1 New2
#          1          
#0  0.963898    0   10
#1  0.305885    1   11
#2  0.400290    2   12
#3  0.753151    3   13
#4  0.474556    4   14
```